# Python EOF error when loop

Tags: python, eoferror

I need to write a python code to print the input like this:

```
while (True):
    output = raw_input()
    print output
```

But when I want to end the loop,I used Ctrl_D,and it says:

```
  File "./digits.py", line 6, in <module>
    output = raw_input()
  EOFError
```

How can I solve it? If possible please give me some simple way because this is the first time I write in python.

Comment: Or is you *really* want ctrl_d to exit a loop, read about exceptions in python

Comment: If this is the first time you write Python, I'd note that you should be really using Python 3, which has been around for **8 years**, unless there a particular pressing reason that you need to be using Python 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `EOFError` is an exception that can be caught with `try`-`except`. Here we break the loop using the `break` keyword if an `EOFError` is thrown:

```
while True:
    try:
        output = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break

    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting a keyword check in your loop?

```
while (True):
    output = raw_input()
    if str(output) == "exit":
        break
    print output
```